# How to query firestore for documents with a timestamp field?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to fetch all documents whose START_DATE is within last 10 days.
For example, if today is *17-04-2020*(DD-MM-YYYY) then I want to fetch documents which have START_DATE *7-04-2020* or above
My Collection structure looks like this:

[image]

I need to do this for my android app in Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to query a timestamp field in a collection, you can use either a java [Date](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date) or Firestore [Timestamp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/Timestamp) object with a range filter.

```
db
    .collection("POLL")
    .whereGreaterThan("START_DATE", date1)
    .whereLessThan("START_DATE", date2)
```

You will have to provide the values for `date1` and `date2` that meet your needs.

Answer (score -1):

I think you have not read the documents, please check this once you will get the solution:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries

Use where query with condition according to your requirement.

Ex:

```
    db.collection("cities")
            .whereEqualTo("capital", true)
            .get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                            Log.d(TAG, document.getId() + " => " + document.getData());
                        }
                    } else {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
                    }
                }
            })

;
```

**EDIT**

https://maye.pwafire.org/articles/using-timestamp-to-filter-and-order-firebase-cloud-firestore-documents/

Comment: I have read the docs. I didn't found anything about quering with timestamp field.

Comment: @sumit try with the link I have shared